# Can a non-zero non-prime ideal become prime in a smaller ring?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

All rings are assumed commutative and unital.

**Some context (feel free to skip right to the questions below).** I am trying to understand to what extent the property "being prime" for an ideal $I$ is intrinsic. For example, how robust "primeness" is under the relative point of view. To this end I consider only such ring morphisms that generically do not (need to) modify $I$. For example, if $I \lhd R$ and $R \xrightarrow{\varphi} S$ is *any* ring morphism, then there are two issues:

- $\varphi$ may not be injective, i.e. it may not preserve $I$ faithfully;
- Even if $\varphi$ is injective, the image $\varphi(I)$ need not be an ideal in $S$, so we need to extend scalars $S \varphi(I)$, which changes $I$ (i.e. the fact that in general the extension of a prime ideal need not be prime is a *non-problem* in this context).

Therefore, what I want to consider is actually the following setting. Let $R \subset S$ be an extension of rings and let $I \subset R$ such that $I \lhd S$ (hence $I \lhd R$). If $I \in \operatorname{Spec} S$, then clearly $I \in \operatorname{Spec} R$ (special case of the simple fact that preimages of prime ideals are prime), so we have robustness in one direction. I have pondered the converse of this, but I have neither been able to find a counter-example nor to prove it, although it seems too general to be true. So, I want to ask the following question:

> **(Q1)** Suppose that $R \subset S$ is a ring inclusion and $0 \neq I \subset R$ is such that $I \lhd S$ and $I \in \operatorname{Spec} R$. Must $I \in \operatorname{Spec} S$?

(If $I = 0$, this is easily satisfied, e.g. $\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Z}[t]/(t^2)$.)

A related secondary question is:

> **(Q2)** Is there an example of a ring inclusion $R \subset S$ such that $\dim R > \dim S$? (The idea being that such a ring extension might provide an ideal that is a counter-example to the above.)

Another potential source of a counter-example is probably a ring extension $R \subset S$ with $\dim R = \dim S = \infty$ (e.g. Nagata's example), but I haven't been able to construct a counter-example.

Comment: (Q1) The ideal $(x^2,x^3) \subseteq k[x]$ is not prime, but its restriction to the subring $k[x^2,x^3]$ is. (Q2) The inclusion $\mathbf Z \subseteq \mathbf Q$ satisfies $\dim R > \dim S$, but there are not a lot of nonzero ideals in $\mathbf Q$.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn  You are correct: I misread the question.

Comment: What about the extension $\mathbb R[x]\subset\mathbb C[x]$ and the ideal $(x^2+1)$ ?

Comment: @DryBones I too gave a similar example at first (as did Jason), but the question is about a situation where $I$ is an ideal in both $R$ and $S$ (here you have to take the extension $IS$ which is the ideal *generated* by $I$ in $S$).

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn: thank you for the nice simple example to (Q1)! I was thinking in a very different direction... To (Q2), yeah the point was for $S$ to be a source of non-trivial ideals, but it no longer matters since you provided an answer to (Q1).

Comment: Oh of course, it's the same ideal, not ideals with the same generator! Ha! XD

Comment: I suppose it's worth saying, for a ring and its normalization $R \subseteq S$, the conductor $\mathrm{Ann}_R(S/R)$ is the largest ideal that is simultaneously an ideal in both rings.  Normalizations then give lots of such examples (if you view Specs of non-normal rings as gluings of normal rings).

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn: you should probably post your example as an answer so as to not leave the question open-ended.

Comment: I was just working on writing up an answer with some further comments!

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn: One general procedure indicated by your example seems to be to look at ideals $\mathfrak{a}$ as **non-unital** $k$-algebras and then picking such an $\mathfrak{a}$ whose *"unitization"* is strictly smaller than the original $k$-algebra.

Comment: @M.G. interesting. I suppose I sometimes think of this example as coming from the free algebras on the monoids $\mathbf N$ and $\mathbf N \setminus \{1\}$, which is kind of similar to what you're describing in that $\mathbf N \setminus \{1\}$ is the monoid obtained from the ideal $\mathbf N_{\geq 2} \subseteq \mathbf N$ (which is only a semigroup) by adjoining a zero element. (The commutative monoid point of view is common in toric and logarithmic algebraic geometry.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted (implicitly) in the comments, it is not very common that $I \subseteq R$ is also an ideal in $S$. For instance, if $R$ and $S$ are domains and $I$ is nonzero, this implies that $\operatorname{Frac} R \to \operatorname{Frac} S$ is an isomorphism, and $R \to S$ is finite if $I$ is finitely generated (e.g. when $R$ is Noetherian).

Indeed, write $K = \operatorname{Frac} R$ and $L = \operatorname{Frac} S$. If $s \in S$ is an element that is $K$-linearly independent from $1$ in $L$ and $x \in I$ is nonzero, then $sx \in L$ cannot be in $K$, contradicting the assumption that $I$ is an $S$-ideal. This proves $K = L$. For the other statement, since $I$ is an $S$-module, we get a ring homomorphism $S \to \operatorname{End}_R(I)$, which is injective since $S$ is a domain and $I$ is nonzero. If $I$ is finitely generated, then so is $\operatorname{End}_R(I)$, hence so is $S$. (I am not really sure if there is an analogue of this in the non-Noetherian case.)

But with these restrictions, you can easily produce examples. For instance, let $S = k[x]$ and let $R$ be the subring $k[x^2,x^3] \cong k[u,v]/(u^3-v^2)$. The ideal $I = (x^2,x^3) \subseteq k[x]$ is contained in $R$ (hence also an $R$-ideal). But $I$ is not prime in $k[x]$, whereas it is prime in $k[x^2,x^3]$ (as it corresponds to the origin $(u,v)$ in $k[u,v]/(u^3-v^2)$).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write up an expanded answer!

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't ask that $S$ be a domain, here is a very simple example, although it might feel as cheating and @R.vanDobbendeBruyn's example is excellent. The only value in this one is perhaps its simplicity.

Anyway, let $R$ be an arbitrary ring with a prime ideal $I\triangleleft R$ and $R'$ another arbitrary (non-zero) ring. Finally, let $S=R\oplus R'$. As $I$ is a prime ideal, $R/I\neq 0$, so $S/I\simeq R/I\oplus R'$ is not a domain, so $I$ cannot be a prime ideal in $S$.

As pointed out by @M.G., this example does not really work, because $R$ is only a subring of $S$ as non-unital rings. So, here is an improvement of (sort of) the same idea:

Let $(R,\mathfrak m,k)$ be a local ring and let $S=R[t] \big /\!\left((t^2)+t\cdot \mathfrak m\right)\simeq R[\varepsilon]$ where $\varepsilon^2=0$ and $\varepsilon\cdot\mathfrak m=0$. Then

1. $R\subseteq S$ is a subring, and
2. $\mathfrak m$ is also an ideal in $S$, but
3. $S/\mathfrak m\simeq k[t]/(t^2)\simeq k[\varepsilon]$, so $\mathfrak m$ is not prime in $S$.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write an answer! But I am not sure I understand your example. What do you mean by a direct sum of rings, their product? If so, how is $R$ a subring of $S$? Are you perhaps assuming the rings to be non-unital?

Comment: You are right. $R$ is only a subring of $S$ as non-unital rings (thought they could both be unital on their own).

Comment: Thanks for the edit! This is a nice and straightforward construction!